# How to use jquery css a:hover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a colour selector to change some elements

```
function(color) {  
    $("#post h1").css("color",color.toHexString());
    $("#footer").css("background",color.toHexString());
    $("#navigation a:hover").css("background",color.toHexString());             
}
```

The `#post h1` and `#foooter` work fine but how can I change the `#navigation a:hover`?

Comment: You'll find that the hover pseudo class is not fully supported by all browsers: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Comment: you don't need to apply `.toHexString()` - it's perfectly valid to use the color names

Comment: @LeeTaylor On anchor tags, it's been supported for ages on every browser.

Comment: @bfavaretto. Yes, you are correct. Time for bed!

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:
Try it:

```
$('#navigation').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'your_color_when_mouse_in'});
},  function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'your_color_when_mouse_out'});
} );
```

Comment: It will change color to `your_color` permanently. Callback function is needed to restore original color.

Comment: Yup @Mics I've got it to work with a callback. I was hoping to find a way to use the a:hover / pseudo, but if not I can do it the long way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Funky fresh alternative!

```
function(color){
    //creates a new style tag
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    //setup your items as actually css instead of style attributes
    vars css = '#post h1{color: '+color.toHexString()+'}';
    css += '#footer, #navigation a:hover{background: '+color.toHexString()+'}';
    //place said css into style tag
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    //add style tag to document
    $('head').append(style);
}
```

This will add a new `<style>` tag to your document containing the css you desire. Plus it will allow you to make use of css native `:hover`!